# Move span higher on page via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using an [easy jquery pullquote](http://blue-anvil.com/archives/easy-jquery-pull-quotes/) plugin and it works fantastically. I am wondering if I can move the span higher in the page using jquery? I'd like the pullquote to appear neat the top of the page rather than directly floated right.

Comment: Like move in the DOM's index, or move on the screen with CSS ?

Comment: show us some code of what are you doing.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Simply edit the float/margin css properties in the plugin's css file. Maybe even add an identical blockquote.pullquote css class but with no floating property ex. blockquote.pullquote.no_float

2.) Edit your template, and place the quote wherever you want it to be displayed using the proper method the plugin requires.

Comment: Regarding #1, placing a negative top margin places it where I want, but the text doesn't wrap around it now. Is there a fix for, or do I have to find another way?

Comment: Try position:relative for the css